# Datatables - show extra / detailed information - reinitialize issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I have a problem with the datatables functionality described [here](https://datatables.net/examples/api/row_details.html).
It works fine when I initialize it once - all the rows expand and hide as designed. When I want to reinitialize it with some other data (let's say user launches another search query), than it pulls the data from the server, displays it, but expanding and hiding functionality doesn't work. Here's my code:

```
function mitarbeitersuche(sButtonName, sQuery)  {
    if(typeof sQuery === "undefined") {
           var sQuery = $('#search-field').val();
    }           

    var sURL = "http://localhost/phb/index.php?kriterium=" + sQuery + "&ButtonName=" + sButtonName;
    $('.dataTables_wrapper').hide();
    $('#mitarbeitersuche').show();
    var oTable = $('#mitarbeitersuche').DataTable( {
        "language": {
            "emptyTable":     "No matching search results."
        },                
        destroy: true,
        "bProcessing": true,
        "bServerSide": false,
        "sAjaxSource": sURL,
        "aoColumns": [
            {
                "className":      'details-control',
                "orderable":      false,
                "data":           null,
                "defaultContent": ''                        
            },
            { "data": "vorname" },
            { "data": "nachname" },
            { "data": "pin" },
            { "data": "banktitle" },                
            { "data": "telefon" },
            { "data": "dw" },
            { "data": "team" }

        ],
        "order": [[1, 'asc']]
    } );
        // Add event listener for opening and closing details
    $('#mitarbeitersuche tbody').on('click', 'td.details-control', function () {
        var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
        var row = oTable.row( tr );

        if ( row.child.isShown() ) {
            // This row is already open - close it
            row.child.hide();
            tr.removeClass('shown');
        }
        else {
            // Open this row
            row.child( format(row.data()) ).show();
            tr.addClass('shown');                        
        }
    } );
}
function format ( d ) {
// `d` is the original data object for the row
var varTitle = (d.ma != '') ? ', ' + d.ma : '';
var varAusbildung = (d.ausbildung == 0) ? 'Nein' : 'Ja';
var varBankTitle = (d.banktitle == null) ? '' : d.banktitle;
return  '<table class="table table-hover table-striped table-condensed table-bordered small" style="margin-top:20px;">'+
    '<tr>'+
        '<th><img class="img-rounded pull-left img-responsive" src="assets/images/p' + d.pin + '.jpg" alt=""><h4 class="pull-down">' + ' ' + d.titel + ' ' + d.vorname + ' ' + d.nachname + varTitle + '</h4></th>'+
        '<td>'+varBankTitle+'</td>'+
    '</tr>'+ 


    '<tr>'+
        '<th>Banktitel</th>'+
        '<td>'+varBankTitle+'</td>'+
    '</tr>'+ 
    '<tr>'+
        '<th>in Ausbildung</th>'+
        '<td>'+varAusbildung+'</td>'+
    '</tr>'+    
    '<tr>'+
        '<th>Funktion (extern)</th>'+
        '<td>'+d.fextern+'</td>'+
    '</tr>'+    
    '<tr>'+    
        '<th>Standort</th>'+
        '<td>'+d.standort+'</td>'+
    '</tr>'+    
    '<tr>'+    
        '<th>Teambezeichnung</th>'+
        '<td><a href="#" onclick="mitarbeitersuche(&quot;but2&quot;, '+ d.teamnr +')">'+d.team+' (Kst: '+ d.teamnr + ')</td>'+
    '</tr>'+    
    '<tr>'+    
        '<th>Team Kurzbezeichnung</th>'+
        '<td>'+d.oekurz+'</td>'+
    '</tr>'+
    '<tr>'+ 
        '<th>Fachfunktion</th>'+
        '<td>'+d.funktion+'</td>'+
    '</tr>'+
    '<tr>'+            
        '<th>Adresse</th>'+
        '<td>'+d.strasse+', ' + d.plz + ' ' + d.ort + '</td>'+
    '</tr>'+    
    '<tr>'+    
        '<th>Mobiltelefon</th>'+
        '<td>'+d.cell+'</td>'+
    '</tr>'+    
    '<tr>'+        
        '<th>Fax</th>'+
        '<td>'+d.persfax+'</td>'+
    '</tr>'+
    '<tr>'+    
        '<th>E-mail</th>'+
        '<td><a href="mailto:'+d.email+'">' + d.email + '</a></td>'+
    '</tr>'+       
'</table>';}
```

So basically when I reinitialize it I get the `oTable.row( tr )` empty, while when I initialize it for the first time it contains a row object. Any idea how to make it work regardless of how many times user will reinitialize it? I'll appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I declared oTable outside `mitarbeitersuche` function as global, and also I moved the event binding outside. So now I have:

```
var oTable;
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('#mitarbeitersuche').on('click', 'td.details-control', function () {
        var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
        var row = oTable.row( tr );

        if ( row.child.isShown() ) {
            // This row is already open - close it
            row.child.hide();
            tr.removeClass('shown');
        }
        else {
            // Open this row
            row.child( format(row.data()) ).show();
            tr.addClass('shown');                        
        }
    } );
   function mitarbeitersuche(sButtonName, sQuery, sPage)  {
        if(typeof sQuery === "undefined") {
               var sQuery = $('#search-field').val();
        }
        if(typeof sPage === "undefined") {
               var sPage = 'index';
        }        
        var sURL = "http://localhost/phb/" + sPage + ".php?kriterium=" + sQuery + "&ButtonName=" + sButtonName;
        $('.dataTables_wrapper').hide();
        $("#main_content").children().hide();
        $('#search-results').show();
        $('#mitarbeitersuche').show();        
        oTable = $('#mitarbeitersuche').DataTable( {
            "language": {
                "emptyTable":     "No matching search results."
            },                
            destroy: true,
            "bProcessing": true,
            "bServerSide": false,
            "sAjaxSource": sURL,
            "aoColumns": [
                {
                    "className":      'details-control',
                    "orderable":      false,
                    "data":           null,
                    "defaultContent": ''                        
                },
                { "data": "vorname" },
                { "data": "nachname" },
                { "data": "pin" },
                { "data": "banktitle" },                
                { "data": "telefon" },
                { "data": "dw" },
                { "data": "team" }

            ],
            "order": [[4, 'desc'], [2, 'asc']],
            "columnDefs": [
                { "width": "15%", "targets": 5 }
            ]
        } );
    function format ( d ) {
    // `d` is the original data object for the row
    var varTitle = (d.ma != '') ? ', ' + d.ma : '';
    var varAusbildung = (d.ausbildung == 0) ? 'Nein' : 'Ja';
    var varBankTitle = (d.banktitle == null) ? '' : d.banktitle;
    return  '<table class="table table-hover table-striped table-condensed table-bordered small" style="margin-top:20px;">'+
        '<tr>'+
            '<th><img onerror="imgError(this);" class="img-rounded pull-left img-responsive" src="assets/images/p' + d.pin + '.jpg" alt=""><h4 class="pull-down">' + ' ' + d.titel + ' ' + d.vorname + ' ' + d.nachname + varTitle + '</h4></th>'+
            '<td></td>'+
        '</tr>'+ 


        '<tr>'+
            '<th>Banktitel</th>'+
            '<td>'+varBankTitle+'</td>'+
        '</tr>'+ 
        '<tr>'+
            '<th>in Ausbildung</th>'+
            '<td>'+varAusbildung+'</td>'+
        '</tr>'+    
        '<tr>'+
            '<th>Funktion (extern)</th>'+
            '<td>'+d.fextern+'</td>'+
        '</tr>'+    
        '<tr>'+    
            '<th>Standort</th>'+
            '<td>'+d.standort+'</td>'+
        '</tr>'+    
        '<tr>'+    
            '<th>Teambezeichnung</th>'+
            '<td><a href="#" onclick="mitarbeitersuche(&quot;but2&quot;, '+ d.teamnr +', &quot;index&quot;)">'+d.team+' (Kst: '+ d.teamnr + ')</a></td>'+
        '</tr>'+    
        '<tr>'+    
            '<th>Team Kurzbezeichnung</th>'+
            '<td>'+d.oekurz+'</td>'+
        '</tr>'+
        '<tr>'+ 
            '<th>Fachfunktion</th>'+
            '<td>'+d.funktion+'</td>'+
        '</tr>'+
        '<tr>'+            
            '<th>Adresse</th>'+
            '<td>'+d.strasse+', ' + d.plz + ' ' + d.ort + '</td>'+
        '</tr>'+    
        '<tr>'+    
            '<th>Mobiltelefon</th>'+
            '<td>'+d.cell+'</td>'+
        '</tr>'+    
        '<tr>'+        
            '<th>Fax</th>'+
            '<td>'+d.persfax+'</td>'+
        '</tr>'+
        '<tr>'+    
            '<th>E-mail</th>'+
            '<td><a href="mailto:'+d.email+'">' + d.email + '</a></td>'+
        '</tr>'+       
    '</table>';
}
}
```

The reason of my problem was multiple executing event listener definition code.